# iptables to forward port to another network

Tags: linux, iptables, portforwarding

I have a VDS running CentOS with two interfaces: eth0 and ham0. eth0 is my WAN interface and has external IP accessible from the Internet, and ham0 is an interface to a small VPN network (Logmein Hamachi).

There are three machines in the VPN network, one of them is a linux box at my home which runs Apache on port 80. This machine is behind ISP's NAT and cannot be seen from outside. 
I want to create a rule on my VDS to forward connections to port 8081 coming from the Internet (eth0 interface) to this linux box inside my VPN network. Something like this:

```
[Internet]   --->  [VDS server with public IP]  --->  [Apache server inside VPN]
```

I used the following rules:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -d *external_ip* --dport 8081 -j DNAT --to *internal_ip*:80
iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp -d *internal_ip* --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p tcp --dst *internal_ip*  -j LOG --log-level warning --log-prefix "[REQUEST_FORWARDED]"
```

But it does not work. I can see a "REQUEST_FORWARDED" message in /var/log/messages, but when I go to the `http://my_eternal_ip:8081/` in my browser, it tries to connect to the host for a very long time, and then shows a message that server did not respond.

What can cause this problem?

Answer (score 4):

I guess you need to make sure "/proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward" has been enabled, if not

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

Above command can help you allow IP forwarding.

Hope this helpful to you.